# TCP header port number occasionally 0

Tags: c, tcp, header

I'm trying to write a simple application to output dst and src TCP port numbers. To test I've tried to apply a pcap filter to only sniff packets to or from port 80. However, I keep getting port numbers of 0, despite everything looking correct to me. About 10% of the time I get a port number in the 5 digits. Can anyone give me any hints as to what I might be doing wrong?

```
#include<pcap.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<net/ethernet.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
#include<netinet/tcp.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

void handle_packet(u_char* args, const struct pcap_pkthdr* pkthdr, const u_char* p)
{
    struct iphdr* ip_hdr;
    struct tcphdr* tcp_hdr;

    ip_hdr = (struct iphdr*) (p+sizeof(struct ether_header));
    tcp_hdr = (struct tcphdr*) (ip_hdr+sizeof(struct iphdr));
    printf("src:%d\n", ntohs(tcp_hdr->source));
    printf("dst:%d\n", ntohs(tcp_hdr->dest));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pcap_t *handle;                /* Session handle */
    char *dev;                     /* The device to sniff on */
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE]; /* Error string */
    struct bpf_program filter;     /* The compiled filter */
    char filter_app[] = "tcp port 80"; /* The filter expression */
    bpf_u_int32 mask;              /* Our netmask */
    bpf_u_int32 net;               /* Our IP */

    /* Define the device */
    dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);

    /* Find the properties for the device */
    pcap_lookupnet(dev, &net, &mask, errbuf);

    /* Open the session in promiscuous mode */
    handle = pcap_open_live(dev, BUFSIZ, 0, 0, errbuf);

    /* Compile and apply the filter */
    pcap_compile(handle, &filter, filter_app, 0, net);
    pcap_setfilter(handle, &filter);

    pcap_loop(handle, 10, handle_packet, NULL);

    pcap_close(handle);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems here. For one, keep in mind that pointer arithmetic in C is *scaled*. So, when you say something like:

```
tcp_hdr = (struct tcphdr*) (ip_hdr+sizeof(struct iphdr));
```

You are in fact advancing far more bytes than you intended (`sizeof(struct iphdr) * sizeof(struct iphdr)` to be exact). To achieve what you'd want you could say:

```
tcp_hdr = (struct tcphdr*) &ip_hdr[1];
```

But this doesn't work either. IP headers don't have a fixed length. Instead you should check the header's `ihl` field and the calculation should look more like this:

```
tcp_hdr = (struct tcphdr*) ((char*)ip_hdr + 4*ip_hdr->ihl); /* ihl is the number of 32-bit words in the header */
```

Caveat: I'm not sure about ethernet frames and if their headers have a fixed length. You'll need to verify that as well.